# Is it possible to render x.jade partial in angular?

Tags: angularjs, pug

The following code works if i  was rendering `some.html` instead of `some.jade`.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/some.jade',  controller: myAppController}).      
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

Is it possible to render a jade file as a partial in angular?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Look at the following [link](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html)

Two important points to note are:

1. `templateUrl: 'partials/some'` instead of `templateUrl: 'partials/some.jade'` and
2. Add the following in routes: ( the code is for expressjs in node)

   ```
   app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res)
    { var name = req.params.name;
      res.render('partials/' + name);
   });`
   ```
3. Quit and relaunch node/express server.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not Angular rendering jade, it's angular calling express which renders jade and angular reads finished rendered html.