# Node Js and Angular Js how to send request from server to client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am working through a tutorial for node js and angular. I am new to angular. The problem I am having is. You can navigate throughout the site fine via the client (angular) navbar, but if you type in the url in the browser it becomes a problem because node does not know about the request url. My simple question is. How do you send a node server request to angular?

Please note that I was trying to prevent the catch all app.get('*'). It causes the site to crash. Not sure why. So having two routes is my solution

here is what I am looking for

```
app.get('/admin/users',function(req,res){
  //This is node. There is already a angular controller that handles this
  //How do I send to angular
  res.send('../../app/public/admin/user-list');//this does not by the way.???
});
```

Angular route that works fine when navigating through nav bar

```
$routeProvider.when('/admin/accounts', {
  templateUrl: '/partials/admin/user-list',
  controller: 'mvUserListCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.admin
})
```

Comment: Access the `../../app/public/admin/user-list` response in your `$http` callback

Comment: Please put more code.. And what kind of Angular router you're using? (ui-router?)

Comment: @Daniel_L can you give me an example on the node side how this is complete? I am not quite sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @SmartyTwiti just added angular route.

Comment: your templateUrl is not referencing an html file. I think you could re-word your question as you are trying to do something completely different.

Comment: @Daniel_L I am using Jade that is why no html reference. I do need back end ref to because if you type in the url it will not work because the server does not know about it. I need the server to pass this to angular somehow. Maybe I am not asking the question correctly. I just need the site to work as normal if your navigating or if you type in the url. Typing it in does not work because node.js knows nothing about a angular handled route

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746063/is-it-possible-to-render-x-jade-partial-in-angular

Comment: @Daniel_L I do have something like this already, but not sure how that correlates with my problem 

app.get('/partials/*',function(req,res){
        //use to get and render Angular partials.
        res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params[0]);
    });

Comment: it's because angular routes aren't necessarily correlated to routes you define in express. in angular, `/partials/foobar` is not `localhost:8000/partials/foobar`, it is `localhost:8000#partials/foobar`. express isn't receiving the GET request because you aren't activating the correct route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the resources using app.get(base_url) in node.js and make the resources available at one location
now when you hit the resources from angular
using http like below

```
return {
        getServiceData: function () {
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: base_url+'patients'
            };

            return $http(req).then(function (result) {
                // alert("data in service = " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
                return result.data;
            });
        }
```

I think this would be helpful